# How can I order by timestamp in a Firestore collection?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order by timestamp, named 'Alpha' as a Field, but I'm hitting an error: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". I've tried following the Docs, but am still not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I detail my code below:

```
func getFollowingPosts() {
            db.collection("iAmFollowing").document(currentUserID!).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR")
                } else {
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        let followedUID = document.get("uid") as? String
                        
                        
                        self.db.collection("posts")
                            .order(by: "Alpha")
                            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID!).getDocuments(completion: { (documents, error) in
                            for documents in documents!.documents {
                                let title = documents.get("Title") as! String
                                let content = documents.get("Content") as! String
                                let username = documents.get("username") as! String
                                let postID = documents.get("postID")
                                let counter = documents.get("counter")
                                self.titleArray.append(title)
                                self.contentArray.append(content)
                                self.usernameArray.append(username)
                                self.postIDArray.append(postID as! Int)
                                self.effectsLabelArray.append(counter as! Int)
                                print(self.titleArray)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                       )}
                    }
                    
                    }
                
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error coming from? I see 1 - you are force-unwrapping some fields which could be nil (`as! String`). Instead, either unwrap with optional value (`as? String`), or unwrap with guard, if you want to skip an entry without that field
Also you are accessing UI elements on potentially background thread - your app will crash intermittently. Wrap any UI access in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Hi - thanks. I'll try this right away. The error is coming from the "for documents in documents!.documents" line

Comment: Ah, you shouldn't be force unwrapping that one either! instead: `guard let documents = ducuments else { /* your query did not return any documents, nothing to loop over */ return }` and then `for document in documents...`

Comment: That definitely silenced the error, but it's not sorting the data. Do you have any ideas about why it's not actually returning any data from the database?

Comment: I think `.whereField` should come before order. You can debug your conditions one by one: first, disable/remove `.whereField` condition and see if sorting alone returns data.Then test `.whereField` separately .

Comment: I've been doing this - testing out .order and .whereField separately. And they both work on their own, but not together.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kiril S., this has been solved. I needed to safely unwrap

```
...
self.db.collection("posts")
     .order(by: "Alpha")
     .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followedUID!).getDocuments(completion: { (documents, error) in
        guard let documents = documents else {
            print("NO DOCUMENTS")
            return
        }
         for documents in documents!.documents {
             let title = documents.get("Title") as! String
             let content = documents.get("Content") as! String
             let username = documents.get("username") as! String
             let postID = documents.get("postID")
             let counter = documents.get("counter")
             self.titleArray.append(title)
             self.contentArray.append(content)
             self.usernameArray.append(username)
             self.postIDArray.append(postID as! Int)
             self.effectsLabelArray.append(counter as! Int)
             print(self.titleArray)
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
     }
...
```

Then, I was prompted by the console to create a Composite Index. After this, I could use .whereField and .orderBy concurrently.